# Weird behaviour of a bath ventilator

Tags: power

I have a weird behaviour of the bath ventilator. The make and model: [Rotheigner Air Basic 100](https://www.hornbach.lu/shop/Ventilateur-en-montage-encastre-pour-puits-Rotheigner-Air-Basic-100-avec-minuterie-et-clapet-anti-retour/8626717/article.html).

When I switch it on it is working for 1 second and stops until I disconnect the power and connect it again.
I thought it is a defective device, so I bought a new, but the new one reveals the same behaviour. 
I did a lot of home electricity before, but now I am completely confused about what could be the reason.
I have tried to switch the polarity (swap the Line and the Neutral cables), I have tried to remove the Earth protection cable - the same behaviour repeats all the time.

"CZAS TIME" regulation has no effect (tried max/min positions - no difference).

Please, any ideas?

[image: How the connection looks like] 
[image]

P.S. Line tester shows voltage on the brown cable; the yellow-green is connected to the Earth socket contact in all sockets.

Comment: Your question will probably be migrated to https://diy.stackexchange.com as this site is for electronics design questions. Your question is missing the make, model and link to installation instructions. You might also explain why you connected an earth wire to a terminal marked 'T'.

Comment: thank you @Transistor for your comment. What should I connect to "T" else? Okay, if I disconnect it - there is no difference in behaviour.

Comment: I'll wait for your question edit to supply the missing information.

Comment: Don’t these things usually have a permanent live and then a switched live to trigger the timer?  What do the instructions say?

Comment: Where is that black wire going?

Comment: @Transistor I have added the make and model, however there is no digital version of the installation instruction. I can make a photo of the paper one if it helps (though it looks like a general text).

Comment: @HandyHowie black wire is not connected. I've just assembled a simple cable to test against a socket

Comment: "I have tried to remove the Earth protection cable" be careful messing with mains stuff can get you hurt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've wired the device up incorrectly.

The three connections it is expecting are:

1) Permanent Live (always connected to live)

2) Switched Live (connected to the live side of the lights)

3) Neutral.

Not live, neutral and earth.

The fan uses the permanent live to power the motor, it looks at the switched live to decide when to do that, and it keeps the motor running for a while after the lights are switched off.

You should check the instructions as going on guess work is dangerous at this voltage, but from the pictures you've posted it looks like L is permanent live,  T is switched live and N is neutral.

As it's wired up now the fan thinks the lights are off, so isn't running.

-- edit --

looking at the documents for the fan, this isn't explained well

https://www.hornbach.lu/data/shop/D04/001/780/498/785/73/8626717_Doc_06_DE_20160503161817.pdf#page=102

"An external switch e.g. light switch, thermostat, etc. must be used to control the device,  it  must  be  located  between  the  L  and  the  T wire."

If you're using this in a bathroom the usual layout would be something like the following....

[image]

(The terminal in the fan in the diagram called SL corresponds to your T terminal, and your local wires may be different colours)

The site from which that image is taken has a good explanation of how
to install a bathroom fan, covering the non electrical aspects as well.

http://www.ultimatehandyman.co.uk/how-to/electrics/install-shower-extractor-fan

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, T should be the Line (in my case) as well as L.

Comment: If you just want the fan to turn on and off when you provide current, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Page 102 of the [Instruction Leaflet](https://www.hornbach.lu/data/shop/D04/001/780/498/785/73/8626717_Doc_06_DE_20160503161817.pdf) says:

> Electrical connection
>
> An external switch e.g. light
> switch, thermostat, etc.
> must be used to control the
> device, it must be located
> between the L and the T
> wire.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnRX5d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Correct wiring.*

T is the 'timer' input. The L will power the fan when T is on and for the preset time after T turns off.

If only the switched wire is available then use circuit b but the fan will power off with the light.